# Can I scale my iPAD app to fit on a iphone automatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPad application built in objective-c i wanted to know if there were any tricks with UIWindow to scale the app to run on an iphone in landscope mode. So that all my assumptions of the frames being ipad size would be ok but it would fit on an iphone. Just to carry around pocket demos etc. I realize things would be hard to press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have it backwards: apps made for the phone can run on the ipad unaltered in either 2x mode (stretched) or in a letterbox.

Comment: Yeah but thats the os doing the lifting. I am programming the app. So i was hoping to do something with the UIWindow or screen to scale it.

Comment: But scale it down? I don't think so. Have you looked at auto layout? If you rework your views to use that, then you are not determining layout by pixel locations anymore.

Comment: yeah, i mean this more of a just a nice to have i guess, i was hoping i could some how, scale the whole UIWindow after its draw to fit on the iphone. Im not looking to recode the app. Like i said just for quick and dirty pocket demos. But i can totally understand if this is a pipe dream. I just figured with all the quartz and coregraphics stuff that I don't know, maybe somone whould have a ingenious hack for this sort of thing.